# Can anyone explain me this makefile example?

Tags: linux, gcc, makefile

```
# Makefile to compare sorting routines

BASE = /home/blufox/base
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -O –Wall
EFILE = $(BASE)/bin/compare_sorts
INCLS = -I$(LOC)/include
LIBS = $(LOC)/lib/g_lib.a \
$(LOC)/lib/h_lib.a
LOC = /usr/local
OBJS = main.o another_qsort.o chk_order.o \
compare.o quicksort.o

$(EFILE): $(OBJS)
    @echo “linking …”
    @$(CC) $(CFLAGS) –o $@ $(OBJS) $(LIBS)

$(OBJS): compare_sorts.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLS) –c $*.c

# Clean intermediate files
clean:
    rm *~ $(OBJS)
```

Comment: Which part do you not understand? (Also, please format your questions properly in the future. I made an attempt, but it still has some oddities, so it's hard to know what we're supposed to look at.)

Comment: For what it's worth, the `$(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLS) –c $*.c` statement looks as if it should be the command associated with a `%o: %.c` pattern rule.

Answer (score 0):

variables substitute to form,
gcc  -O –Wall -o /home/blufox/base/bin/compare_sorts main.o another_qsort.o chk_order.o compare.o quicksort.o main.c another_qsort.c chk_order.c compare.c
for eg:
$(OBJS) = main.o another_qsort.o chk_order.o compare.o quicksort.o